# aligning text to absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

Part of a complex form design... I want to place two items such that the second is absolutely positioned (the data) and the first is butted up to the left hand side of the second. I'm guessing this would need a third (enclosing) div, something like:

```
<divMain>
<div3><div1>name</div1><div2>data</div2></div3>
</divMain>
```

Varying sizes/kerning of the name and data fields due to fonts etc make accurate calculation impossible.

Is there a way of doing this in CSS ~without~ jquery, javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.main{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}
.div3{
   background: red;
    position : absolute;
    top:50%;
  width:100px;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  left:50%;
  display:flex;
}

.div2{
    background:white;
  flex:1;
  }

.div1{
   background:grey;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="div3"><div class="div1">name</div><div class="div2">A lot of data</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. The position of the left bottom corner of div2 needs be fixed (absolute) with reference to div3. Here it seems to change with different data width.

Comment: Maybe some more background... This is for a complex grid-based form and the bottom left of a data field must be at a specified x,y grid position. The name part must be immediately to the left of the data (right-aligned, if you like). The x,y bit is easy if applied to the whole name=>data pair but not what is reqd.